# Create continuous line network using PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgis, postgis-topology

I have shapefile which doesn’t have continuous network. I want to connect it to the nearest line and create continuous line from it. the postgis table has three columns- gid,objectid and geom.The geom is in multi line.now i want to connect this line to the nearest line and make it one line .
i try this query but its not connecting to the nearest line.

select st_makeline(st_linemerge(geom::geometry)) from footpath

[image].